# Implementing a bar in a WPF program

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I'm looking to make a WPF application that uses an illuminated bar as a "progress bar." Not in the traditional sense such as a program loading, but to display to the user how far he has progressed in a certain objective/task. Below is an example of the bar I am trying to describe.

[Progress Bar](http://bing-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/progress-bar-main.jpg)

I would like to make a path using multiple bars connected to each other but have no idea how to go about putting them in the program. Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: The usual way to go about this would be using the [`ProgressBar` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx) with a [custom control template](http://wpftutorial.net/templates.html). I'm not sure what you mean by "a path using mutiple bars connected to each other", though; do you mean one bar will start filling only after the previous one has reached 100%?

Comment: YES!! That's exactly what I mean Mapper. The bar will be connected by a point but when one is 100% the other will become another percent until the defined thing is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @O.R.Mapper correctly pointed out, the **[ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx)** control is the correct way to go, using a control template to make it look however you'd like.

Regarding your second question: if you want the value of one ProgressBar to be dependent on a value of another ProgressBar, you should modify the **[Maximum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.maximum.aspx)** property to correctly show the intended value.

For example, if you have one Main progress bar, which should reach 100% only after 2 other tasks have been completed - give it a `Maximum` value of 200, 
then set its value by using a calculation such as:
`MainProgressBar.Value = firstTaskValue + secondTaskValue`.
It will only reach 100% after the 2 tasks have been completed...
You can play with this however you want, for instance if one task is more important then another:
`MainProgressBar.Value = firstTaskValue + 2 * secondTaskValue`.

Anyways, this is logic you'll have to implement by yourself...